# String to Int64 Conversion in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

NestJs we cannot directly convert int to int64 we need to use some libraries for conversion the issue with libraries is it converts the int into BigInt but it appends 'n' at the end can you suggest or provide alternative how to further proceed.

Comment: Have you tried Int64??

Comment: no, can you explain me more for that I don't find that library.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-int64